# SharePoint 2013 List permission

Tags: list, sharepoint

I want to create a list in SharePoint 2013 that can be access by multiple users but shows to each user their records only.
For example: Time and Attendance list to show the records of the user only. And only the managers to view all the records.

Answer (score 0):

In this case each list item would need to stop inheriting permissions from the parent and only assign the permissions for those that can edit and read the record.

Are you trying to do this through the UI or Code?

To do that that through the UI do the following:
1. From the list view, click the ellipses for the list item
2. Click Shared With -> Advanced
3. Click "Stop Inheriting Permissions" in the ribbon
4. Remove/Add the permissions you need

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view on the list and add filter to show only items for the current user only.Sample:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdX4R.jpg)

Or if you want to display only the items that were created by the user. Go to List settings > Advanced settings and set the item-level permission. Sample: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWizy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you using SharePoint Designer 2013.

1) Create a SP2010 Workflow Called "Set Item Level Permission"

2) Trigger = When Item Created/Change

3) Add "Impersonation Step" -> Replace "Read/Write" permission to Current Item.

4) in your list item, you can select multiple people picker field to grant them with different permission when item created/change.

Example: "Name of Employee" is a people picker for my case.
for Manager, you can hardcode the "Manager Group" (sp group)

[image]